# Access to code-coverage results in Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

My current project is hosted in Visual Studio Online. With each build I can see what my code coverage is.

However, I would like to write a build task that would fail the build or provide a warning if the code-coverage decreases when compared to the previous build.

Does VSO offer this kind of information? Can anyone point me in the right direction or is what I'm asking currently not possible with VSO?

Comment: I'd argue that you shouldn't do that. Code coverage gives you useful information on areas of your code that aren't tested at all, but having dogmatic enforcement of a particular coverage percentage is just going to lead to people gaming the system by writing "tests" that don't test anything.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, does it? As a team we decided that we want to try this. We want to prevent that our release builds are decreasing in code coverage. We don't enforce a specific number, we just want to prevent it from dropping. Because it means that you added code without a unit test.

Comment: It wasn't intended to answer the question. I wanted to point out that code coverage is a metric that's worth looking at, but it's not an indicator of code quality. If your code coverage drops from 50% to 49% because someone added some straightforward boilerplate code where testing would add dubious value, then failing a build based on that is crazy. What code coverage is telling you is where you're not testing **at all**, so you can identify critical business logic that's not being tested. Blindly failing builds because of a decrease isn't helping you identify those scenarios.

Comment: Failing might be a bit harsh - a warning would be nice though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now there is no built-in action, task or script which does this. It should be possible to request the previous successful build from a custom task and compare the values though...

Visualizing the trend can be achieved through the SonarQube integration. Though it doesn't have a way yet to fail the build or issue a warning on a negative trend, it at least makes it very visible.

When combined with Git, it may be a bit harder though, as a single build definition can cover multiple branches, and "the previously successful build" may be a completely different version of the software you're building. Causing all kinds of false negatives.

Comment: With regards to your last statement: it wouldn't be hard to simply set a builddefinition to a fixed branch. The warning is correct although already anticipated. Thanks for the reply.